# "He was the first person to do" vs. "He was the first person who did"

Tags: meaning, relative-clauses, infinitives

I saw the following sentence in an book:

> He was the first person of such stature in Wuzhou to devote himself to teaching and creating a community of learning.

Does it mean anything different from the following sentence?

> He was the first person of such stature in Wuzhou who devoted himself to teaching and creating a community of learning.

Comment: They mean exactly the same thing - an infinitive, versus a relative clause- essentially two ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: @WS2: I think sometimes *the first person to [verb]* is a better fit than *the first person who [verbed]* in contexts where [verbing] was some kind of "goal" first achieved by the specified subject.  So maybe *X was the first man to set foot on the moon, Y was the first man who died in space*. Or maybe not, I dunno.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm with you. I think there's a small nuance of success with "first to". It sounds odd to say, "*The first man to die in space*", like it's some kind of achievement. My feeling is "first who" doesn't have any nuance in either direction. Care to make an answer of it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. But it would be an especially fine nuance for an English learner, I suspect.

Comment: Thank you all. These comments help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

While these can certainly denote the same situation, the first option is more common and sounds more natural. Here's [one of many possible comparisons on Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20first%20to%20be%2Cthe%20first%20who%20be_INF&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

The second formulation, though not actually ambiguous when you think about it, risks misdirecting the listener, because the opening part sounds like it fully qualifies the subject. That is, the relative clause "who did" sounds non-restrictive instead of restrictive. (Again, on reflection, one realizes it must be restrictive, but it's not always immediately apparent, especially with the wrong intonation.) The "to do" formula can't exist outside of the first half, so they're bound a little more tightly and hence there's less misdirection.

Comment: Thank you Luke. The comparison on Google Ngrams is fascinating :)

Comment: The second sentence is easier to understand as, *He was the first person of such stature in Wuzhou who **had** devoted himself to teaching and creating a community of learning.*